# Send a curl PUT request with headers

Tags: curl, http-headers, put

I have to apply to a website `http://http://careers.codemymobile.com/` . i have to send the request in as the format given in the above link. for this i am trying to send a request to the host like this.

`curl --request PUT 'http://careers.codemymobile.com ' --data 'name=myname , email=myemail@gmail.com, phone=+919989988999, experienced=true, profile=PHP' --header 'Host: http://careers.codemymobile.com , X-CodeMyMobile-Key: e97d6b85fc85568a63bcfce872caeee028ea5b61, Content-type:application/json'`

but it is given a an error `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'careers.codemymobile.com '`

Can someone tell me where I am making a mistake in sending this request? 
help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

cUrl is picky about the order of arguments and how they're formatted.

The URL has to always be last, and try using double quotes instead of single. Don't wrap the URL in quotes.

Try something like this.

```
curl --request PUT --data "name=myname , email=myemail@gmail.com, phone=+919989988999, experienced=true, profile=PHP" --header "Host: http://careers.codemymobile.com , X-CodeMyMobile-Key: e97d6b85fc85568a63bcfce872caeee028ea5b61, Content-type:application/json" http://careers.codemymobile.com
```

Comment: thank you @Mathew ,thanx for answering , i sent the request in the format as you told but it returns <html> <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx</center> </body> </html>

Comment: @SajidAhmad that just means the server didn't like the request, but it does mean it received it.